# How to findAll entires(posts) which contain at least one specified tag. Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I`m trying to retrieve only entries(posts) which possess a specific tag. One entry can have many tags, so I use List of objects. But I don't know how to construct a proper command in Controller class, actually I'm afraid I’m completely lost here.

Entry entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class BlogEntry {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String title;

@Column(name = "published_date")
private Date publishedDate;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable
private List<TagBlog> blogTags; /* Multiple tags to one entry */
```

And my Tag entity:

```
@Entity
public class TagBlog {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String tag;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="blogTags")
private List<BlogEntry> entries;
```

In my EntryService class I wanted to perform this kind of sort "findByTagBlogIn" which I wish would return List of posts that possess specific tag.

```
public List<BlogEntry> findAllByTags(List<TagBlog> tag){                            

    List<BlogEntry> blogEntry = entryRepository.findByTagBlogIn(tag);

    return blogEntry;
}
```

But I don't know how to refer to it in Controller class. How can I retrieve only entries with specific tag? Something like this? But how to pass List of tags as a parameter, maybe it should be String?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome")
public String retrieveTaggedEntry(Model model, ?List of tags?){

model.addAttribute("entriesWithTag", entryService.findAllByTags(TagBlog tag));

    return "redirect:/welcome.html"; 
}
```

In the welcome.jsp file I would like to iterate throught whole List of tags that had been assigned to specific entry(post) like in example below (between the arrows "---> <---" is the part of my conserns):

```
<c:forEach items="${entries}" var="entry"> <!--"entries" refers to List of BlogEntry-->
<table>
            <tr>
                    <td>Entry No. ${entry.id }</td>
                    <td>${entry.title}</td>
                    <td>
                    Tags: ---> #${entry.? blogTag.tag ?}, <--- 
                    </td>
                    <td>Published: ${entry.publishedDate}</td>
                    <td>
                        <spring:url value="/delete_entry/${entry.id}.html" var="url" />
                        <a href="${url}">Delete</a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</c:forEach>
```

By working it out later, I want to perform a sort (by mapping spring:url value="/tag/${some_tag_as_a_String}.html") by entries that possess a specific tag.

Maybe there is an easier way to return posts only with specific tag? But I guess it would be easier for me to work with what I got here.  Anyway, any solution provided is appreciated.

I'm willing to add any additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you want to send the whole `TagBlog` object to the Controller? Why not just the tag ID or tag text? E.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome")
public String retrieveTaggedEntry(Model model, @RequestParam List<String> tags) {
    // Do something with your tags
}
```

Comment: There is no specific reason. Let me check what I can do with List<String> and how it works in the controller class.

Comment: Well, looks like I can't use List<String> since it throws an error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: BlogEntry, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(stringTag)]